# Remove all .html files - if else statement won't work

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is my first bash script. I need to remove all .html files from the current folder.

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HTML_FILE_COUNT=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" | wc -l)

echo "Remove $HTML_FILE_COUNT file(s) with .html extension (yes / no)?"

echo -n "Answer: "
read ANSWER

if [ [$ANSWER = "yes"] ]; then
    echo "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" -delete)"
    echo "Files have been removed!"
elif [ [$ANSWER = "no"] ]; then
    echo "No file has been removed!"
else
    echo "Unknown command!" 
fi
```

However, the `if else` block returns only `Unknown command`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note too that `find` is not really needed here as you could just as well have used `./*.html` (unless you are afraid to match directories too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have whitepsace between the `[ ]` brackets and your variables/string.

```
if [[ $ANSWER = "yes" ]]; then
```

...

```
elif [[ $ANSWER = "no" ]]; then
```

Comment: This did the trick! Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - please mark it as an accepted answer. Thank you.